# How do I input multiple phylogenetic trees into R?

Tags: r, phylogeny

I have 10,000 trees, as individual *.tre* files, in my working directory, but I can't seem to load them all into R.

I tried this:

```
library(ape)

temp=list.files(pattern="*.tre")

mamtrees=lapply(temp,read.tree)
```

Which yielded the following error message:

```
Error in nchar(tree) : invalid multibyte string, element 592
In addition: Warning message:
In grepl("'", tree) : input string 592 is invalid in this locale
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Most likely you are picking up some other files? Try temp=list.files(pattern=".tre$"). This ensures it all ends with .tre

Comment: That worked! Thank you!